# Is it possible to bypass the signature of a module for debugging purpose?

Tags: ocaml

I try to understand a strange behaviour of some functions of a module that rely on a variable of this module masked by the signature of this module. I would like to print this variable at some points of the program, but since it is masked, I do not known how to access it.

Moreover, this module is part of a big project that I do not want to modify and recompile myself.

Is it possible to access this variable for debugging purposes ? Even doing temporarily dirty things ?

EDIT: here some representative code

```
module type S = sig val f : unit -> unit end
module M : S = struct let x = ref 0 let f () = Format.printf "%d@." !x; incr x end
```

How to access `M.x` ?

Comment: Do you mean with `ocamldebug` ?

Comment: With `ocamldebug` or coding. I am interested in both.

Comment: Try to give some [MCVE] in your question, or some code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can!

First, you can just hide the signature for a while :

```
module type S = sig val f : unit -> unit end
module M (* : S *) = struct
  let x = ref 0
  let f () = Format.printf "%d@." !x; incr x 
end
```

Or you can show `x` in the signature :

```
module type S = sig 
  val x : int ref 
  val f : unit -> unit 
end
module M : S = struct
  let x = ref 0
  let f () = Format.printf "%d@." !x; incr x 
end
```

As you prefer. In both cases, `M.x` will be available outside the module.

You can even define a function `print_x` like this :

```
module type S = sig 
  val print_x : unit -> unit 
  val f : unit -> unit 
end
module M : S = struct
  let x = ref 0
  let print_x () = Format.printf "%d@." !x
  let f () = Format.printf "%d@." !x; incr x 
end
```

and use `M.print_x ()` wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks, but all your solutions modify the code of the module, and I do not want to do that.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that's impossible. If the signature is in a `.mli` you can try to recompile but without this file but if you don't want to modify the signature or the module you won't be able to do it (as far as my knowledge goes).